# Can Solaris x86 run old applications that were compiled for Solaris Sparc?

Tags: x86, emulation, solaris, endianness, sparc

Is the x86 edition able to run old apps? Does it take care of all endianness stuff?

Please don't send me to Google :) I honestly tried and was not able to find a solid answer with some references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. You must use an emulator like [QuickTransit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTransit) to do that

You can find more information on Google with the appropriate keywords

- [Running Solaris Sparc Apps on X86 Solaris](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/33683-running-solaris-sparc-apps-x86-solaris.html)
- [Runing Solaris SPARC software on x86-64](http://blog.boreas.ro/2008/03/runing-solaris-sparc-software-on-x86-64.html)
- [Transitive Translates SPARC Solaris Apps on Windows](http://www.serverwatch.com/news/article.php/3759691/Transitive-Translates-SPARC-Solaris-Apps-on-Windows.htm)
- [Solaris SPARC to x86 software highway opens](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/03/19/transitive_solaris_sparc_x86/)
- [Sparc: "emulate" it on x86 (windows, linux) & run solaris 10. Anyone done it?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.solaris/lSNtSZfQoZQ)
- [Export an application using Sparc architecture to intel x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38991844/995714)

If you have the source code it'll be easier to do a recompile to the target platform. You can read

- [Solaris SPARC to Solaris x86 Porting Guide](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c01936557-1%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)
- [Just one source code can be used on Solaris 11 sparc and x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29230671/995714)