# Just one source code can be used on Solaris 11 sparc and x86?

Tags: x86, solaris, difference, pam, sparc

I've made some access control program with PAM, and it can be compiled on Solaris 11 sparc and x86 now.

I know that the architecture is difference between sparc and x86.
Would I test on each platform? or just one platform case?

thank you, read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell without knowing precisely what APIs and features your program is using but assuming it compiles well in both platforms and works fine in one of them, the risk for it to fail in the other is extremely low.

Solaris is built from single source trees and has an extremely low number of architecture specific APIs/commands. The higher risk would be an issue with endianness.